# Ternary conditional operator for the left-hand operand in C#

Tags: c#, variable-assignment, conditional-operator

Is it possible to choose the destination variable based on some inline condition without the if statement?

```
(!RTL ? padLeft : padRight) = NearBorder.LineWidth;
```

Comment: What do intend that statement to mean? Are `padLeft` and `padRight` variables? If you mean *"depending on the boolean state of `RTL`, set one of the `padLeft` or `padRight` variables to the value `NearBorder.LineWidth`"*, then no, as far as I know, C# doesn't allow that. Your question really needs to show the declaration of `padLeft` and `padRight` and the type of `RTL`

Comment: **Welcome to StackOverFlow, @AndreyDryazgov !** Could you elaborate, please? I'm not sure I follow your question.

Comment: In that example the RTL is a property of type bool; padLeft, padRight, and NearBorder.LineWidth are of type float. I'm just looking for a way to avoid duplicating the right-hand operand without creating a new variable for the temporary result.

Comment: Check out my answer below. If you're using a recent enough compiler it should do what you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a new enough version of C# (7.2+), and those variables are locals or fields then you can use `ref locals`;

```
(!RTL ? ref padLeft : ref padRight) = NearBorder.LineWidth;
```

See this [sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgJgIwFgBQyDMABGgQMIEDeOB1RqqFVNTYAdsAQB4C8ADANyMm1VuwCevAdiE0ARgHs5EAjK4EA4gFNgAIQUQAFAEpJ06vpkEA/AQBOGgGacCIWw4KjDBVQFYTp5OgAnPocnn7SAcEe4QQAvoIEAA42YABuAIbAGkToAGzKeupauopGXgB8BAAimRoAKmAAthoAdABycgDuLQ0AxgDWAM4EAKQE9Fyq/DixQA==) link for an example. Note that the [proposal docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.2/conditional-ref) (which refer to this as `conditional ref`) indicate that this is still a proposal. The [Championed GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/223) issue is still *open* but seems to indicate the only thing missing is a true specification. This [comment on that issue](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/223#issuecomment-366009269) suggests it was all implemented as part of the greater [`ref readonly`](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/csharp-7.2/readonly-ref.md) theme.

All aside, this code works for me in both SharpLab and locally in VS2019 (latest, non-preview, using dotnet core 3.0)

If those variables were fields, you *could* also use a `ref return` and encapsulate the logic into a function. For example:

```
// class fields
int padLeft, padRight;  
// ref returning method 
private ref int GetPad() => ref (!RTL ? ref padLeft : ref padRight);
// actually use it
void SetPad() {
    // assignment to a method! 
    GetPad() = NearBorder.LineWidth;
}
```

For more information about the concept of `ref locals` and `ref returns` (originally part of C# 7), see this [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/ref-returns) article.

Comment: Very cool ! I've just tried even the following code: (GetBool() ? ref x : ref y) += 5; and it works for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Well it is sort of possible if you use the ternary operator to select a delegate and have the delegate do the assignment. Its doubtful you'd see this technique in actual use. An `if` statement is the usual way to do it.

```
    var a = new Action<int>( i => padLeft = i );
    var b = new Action<int>( i => padRight = i );

    (!RTL ? a : b)(NearBorder.LineWidth);
```

Comment: Yes, but I wish there were a more production-ready way to do the same thing. It must be easy from the compiler standpoint to keep the result of right-hand expression somewhere before making a decision about the target variable.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try it and see what happens:

```
var a =1; var b =1; var c=1;
(a == 1? b : c) = 4
```

if you run this you will get

> The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or
>   indexer
>   Which is referring to everything left of that = sign.

You can however assign to one variable or the other conditionally, but you have to use your assignment variable twice.  This would work like you expect:

```
!RTL ? padLeft = NearBorder.LineWidth : padRight = NearBorder.LineWidth;
```

however In your specific case, I would probably use different code.

```
padLeft = RTL ? NearBorder.LineWidth: 0;
padRight = !RTL ? NearBorder.LineWidth: 0;
```

Comment: Your different version has a different result--his code doesn't zero the variable not used.